# Joining unnest variable BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to join two tables where the only joinable key/variable is in a recorded how can I unnest it and join both tables?

I tried so many queries for hours, and nothing seems to be working. I would really appreciate the help

```
SELECT
    bb.brand_name,
    warehouse_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vi.is_active =TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Total_Active_Listed,
FROM
    `table1` AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    unnest (brand) bb
LEFT JOIN 
    unnest (warehouse_info) wi
LEFT JOIN 
    unnest (vendor) vi 
JOIN
    `table2`, unnest(items) AS it ON p2.sku = it.sku
```

Comment: What is the error? Why you add the `mysql` tag? If you can add the structure of each table will helps to investigate the issue.

Comment: @DamiãoMartins I edited it thanks for the info so what I am trying to do is to unnest items from table two so I can join using sku hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

A few things to begin... it isn't clear where `p2.sku` comes from and you don't have a `group by` statement.

Either way, it will probably be easier to separate your logic into CTEs, especially with multiple `unnest()` statements.  Consider something similar to the following:

```
 with t1 as (
  SELECT
    bb.brand_name, 
    warehouse_name, -- unclear prefix
    sku,            -- unclear prefix
    SUM(CASE WHEN vi.is_active =TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Total_Active_Listed
  From  `table1`
  LEFT JOIN unnest (brand) bb
  LEFT JOIN unnest (warehouse_info) wi
  LEFT JOIN unnest (vendor) vi
  group by 1,2,3
 ),
 t2 as (
   select distinct sku
   from `table2`
   left join unnest(items) it
 )
 select
  t1.brand_name,
  t1.warehouse_name,
  t1.Total_Active_Listed
from t1
inner join t2 using(sku)
```